(Adobe Animate CC) How to batch import multiple SVG files to different keyframes in order to create one flash file?
I am attempting to import multiple (thousands to be specific) SVG files in Adobe Animate CC 2018 using the "Import to Stage" option to make one SWF (Flash) file.
Using the "Import to Stage" option and selecting all of my SVG files, I am presented with the option to:

"Import all paths to same frame and layer"
"Import each path to different layers"
"Import each path to different keyframes"

I picked the last option since that is exactly what I am trying to do.
However, it only allows me import the SVG files one at a time rather than the whole sequence in one go, having me to click on the option "Import each path to different keyframes" and the "OK" button for every single SVG file that I have out of thousands. I have done a bit of research and noticed someone else is also having the same problem as me, but haven't found any solutions on the official Adobe's Community page.
I would like to know if there some workaround to efficiently solve this issue without having to click the same options for thousands of files that I am trying to import?
